# NavigationController landscape and portrait

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I have two `ViewController` one support orientation another not, but when I rotate in second `ViewController` (the one which supports orientation) to landscape and back to first `ViewController`(doesn't support orientation) at the meantime second view still remain landscape it will change the first view become landscape as well but it not supposed to be landscape while first `ViewController` is not support orientation, how do I prevent this ?

The thing I want is the first view will always be portrait no matter how you rotate the phone especially when back from second view and it was in landscape.

Answer (score 0):

in `viewWillAppear:Animated` of your first controller, call

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
```

And of course, set up the shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation to return YES only on UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait.

Comment: this only rotate the device back to potrail but my view was still in landscape,others way?

Comment: You need to make sure the correct view controller is receiving the rotate events.  Some times adding a view controller will cause that to receive events even after removing it;  Also, I know with at least TabBarViewControllers, it doesn't send rotate events to its children, so you have to override.

Comment: I think Ed was meant [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]; above source is only change orientation of status bar not the views.

Comment: Changing the status bar orientation changes the view's orientation.

Answer (score -1):

in viewWillAppear:Animated of your first controller, call
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];